# error when try to use laravel passport in android studio using post method

Tags: android, laravel, laravel-5, android-volley

so i just learn to use laravel passport on my project, i got this error message

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

i use post method in my volley android and i use post method in laravel route but i got this error, but when i try delete the passport token the error doesnt appear  heres my route

```
  Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
  return $request->user();
   });

 Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@login');
Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});
```

and heres my controller

```
      $input = $request->all();
    // // $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
    // $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('nApp')->accessToken;
    // $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    // $success['message']="berhasil";


     $response=[
         'success'=>1,
         'message'=>'berhasil tod',
        'token'=> $user->createToken('nApp')->accessToken
      ];

     return json_encode($response);
```

Comment: please put your  all route file code in api.php file.